# Why am I getting 'Instance of Future<String> ' instead of value?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I made an app using Flutter and I have a Column like this:

```
 Column(
 crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: [
         questionList[_level - 1]['hintImage'] =='none'
             ? Container()
               : Text(getDownloadImageUrl(questionList[_level -1]['hintimagename']).toString(),),
),
```

And the Method getDownloadImageUrl :

```
  Future<String> getDownloadImageUrl(String name) async {
    StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(name);

    final String url = (await ref.getDownloadURL()).toString();

    return url;
  }
```

If I print that url inside the method it prints me the url I am expected, but if I put it in a widget like that I'm getting ' Instance of Future '.

I have a list of questions, but not all questions do have an image, that's why I'm trying to render them programmatically, not 1 by 1 and store them in some local variables.

How can I get the actual string I'm expected, maybe I misunderstood the concept of async await, or used them wrong. Thank you in advance for your helping!

Comment: what's the output of  `Text(getDownloadImageUrl(questionList[_level -1]['hintimagename']).toString(),),` ? 
i mean what te Future function return inside a widget you said an instance of future what that means ?

Comment: The output is " Instance of ' Future<String> ' "